# Java Game: Changing the brightness or transparency of a image

Tags: java, opengl

**Hello Everyone,**

I am working on a 2D tile game and I want to work on light so at night it'll be darker and at night brighter. If I can't change the brightness, I could have it fade from a brighter texture to a darker. Here is the image drawing function I have:

```
public static void drawRectTexRot(Texture tex, float x, float y, float width, float height, float angle) {
    tex.bind();
    glTranslatef(x + width / 2, y + height / 2, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(- width / 2, - height / 2, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex2f(width,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex2f(width, height);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, height);
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Any help would be great. :)

-Ekrcoaster

Comment: I don't see any illumination in your code. (Besides the fact that you are using a terribly outdated version of OpenGL).

Comment: Is there a simpler way of doing it? I know nothing about opengl and am using indie programmers drawing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you cange transparency of Graphics2D object by method :

```
float opacity = 0.5f;
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, opacity));
```

Value 0 is for transparent and 1 is opaque. In this case whatever you  draw next 
will be half transparent.

To change brightness of Image use [`RescaleOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html). Example :

```
RescaleOp rescaleOp = new RescaleOp(1.3f, 0, null);
rescaleOp.filter(image, image);
```

The first argument of `RescaleOp` constructor determines brightness scale. Value of `1f` means the same brightness, value `0.75f` means image is darker by 25%. Value of `1.3f` makes image brighter by 30 %.